# VBA Adodb : concatenation of values

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I would like to use in my query the key like this: '"prod.cd_produit"'||'"/"'||'" & strQ & "'.
Here, the values of my variables are: prod.cd_produit= 53 and & strQ & =350, so I would like to have 53/350 as a key.

I'm wondering if it's right to write '"prod.cd_produit"'||'"/"'||'" & strQ & "' (I don't want to have any spaces neither at right nor at left). This is a part of my code :

```
Public Sub INFO_PROTO34(ByRef strQ As String)
...........................................
 " sousc.lp_etat_doss not in ('ANNUL','A30','IMPAY') and sousc.is_produit = prod.is_produit" & _
        " and  '"prod.cd_produit"'||'"/"'||'" & strQ & "' = proto.cd_protocole ",
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @pizzettix thank you, do you mean like this : and  prod.cd_produit &" / " & strQ = proto.cd_protocole ", cnn_Pegase, adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic

Comment: It doesn't work :(

Comment: @pizzettix what do you mean "somme texte" ? Sorry I mostly worked on SAS,  I started VBA recently,  my idea is that I need only || between the variables for concatenation. You mean that it doesn't work for cd_Produit and strQ beacause one is variable and another is string ?

Comment: If you want to concatenete strings or variables use`&` : `var1="Hello "`, `var2="world!"` concatenate var1 and var2 as follows `var1 & var2` the results will be `Hello wordl!`. If you want you can write this too: `"Hello "  & "world!"`the result will be the same.

Comment: @pizzettix thank you ! If I need  /  between the variables, can I write:        
  prod.cd_produit &" / " & strQ = proto.cd_protocole

Comment: @pizzettix thank you, seems don't work. I put this :                                                                If Len(numero_de_police) > 0 Then
        RECSET.Open " select proto.b_perf_cma as b_perf_cma from db_dossier sousc,db_produit prod, db_protocole proto" & _
            " where sousc.no_police = '" & numero_de_police & "' and sousc.cd_dossier = 'SOUSC' and " & _
            " sousc.lp_etat_doss not in ('ANNUL','A30','IMPAY') and sousc.is_produit = prod.is_produit and  prod.cd_produit & " / " & strQ &" = " & proto.cd_protocole ", cnn_Pegase, adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228048/discussion-between-marie-and-pizzettix).

Comment: Is the value in `proto.cd_protocole` actually "53/350" ?  It's not very clear what you need to do.

Comment: @TimWilliams Hello William, yes, it is, therefore I need to concatent the prod.cd_produit and & strQ &.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```vb
RECSET.Open " select proto.b_perf_cma as b_perf_cma from db_dossier sousc,db_produit prod, " & _
            " db_protocole proto where sousc.no_police = '" & numero_de_police & "' " & _
            " and sousc.cd_dossier = 'SOUSC' " & _
            " and sousc.lp_etat_doss not in ('ANNUL','A30','IMPAY') " & _
            " and sousc.is_produit = prod.is_produit " & _
            " and prod.cd_produit||'/'||'" & strQ & "' = proto.cd_protocole ", _
              cnn_Pegase, adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic
```

helps to spend some time formatting your SQL so it's more readable (for us *and* you...)

Comment: Thank you very much ) Yes, it is more better !